# Getting text-overflow in a flex-box to work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following "top bar" which has as part of it data for the user. It will also contain his name. The code is as follows:

```css
html, body, ul, li, a, input { box-sizing: border-box; outline: 0px solid transparent; }
.title-bar {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  height: 128px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #999;
  float: left;
}
.user-info {
  width: 128px;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  background-color: inherit;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
.user-info span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: '.';
}
.user-info .circle {
  border: 2px solid #369;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 8px 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-out;
  width: 32px;
}
.user-info .circle:hover { border-width: 4px; }
.user-info .container {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 6px;width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
  <div class="user-info">
    <a href="#" class="circle"></a>
    <span>Johnny B. Testname</span>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="circle"></a>
      <a href="#" id="log-off" class="circle first" title="Log Off">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, "Johnny B. Testname" cuts off on the bottom. This is because I have set `overflow: hidden;` on the span (it would otherwise push the other flex-items around which I do not want).

I was looking for a solution to "dynamically change the font-size," but I don't think that would look good (and I couldn't find anything workable). I found instead `text-overflow;` and as you can see, I've set it to `text-overflow: '.';

Only problem is: it isn't getting to the point where it needs to text-overflow. I've tried setting `flex-shrink: 1;` (which wouldn't matter as that's the default), `display: inline;` (I got desperate) and other CSS styles but none of them have fixed the problem. I don't want to set `height` or `width` as I still want that `span` to be dynamic.

Maybe I am using text-overflow wrong, but I think I am using per the [MDN specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow). I have also made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4lackof/yvf7uqd5/) for this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yvf7uqd5/1/)

```
.user-info span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* for getting the end dots */
  display: inline-block; /* for making span a block (inline-block) so that it accepts max-width */
  max-width: 90%; /* specify the width */
  white-space: nowrap; /* for keeping text in single line */
}
```